# access html classes like css `tag[class*="samepart-"]` in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this css:

```
tag[class*="samepart-"] {
  /* css code for all html classes with "samepart-" in their class name */
}
```

With this html:

```
<div class="samepart-a">some html a</div>
<div class="samepart-b">some html b</div>
<div class="samepart-c">some html c</div>
```

Now I want to get all the html classes with "samepart-" in JS without adding an extra html class to the "samepart-" classes.

This is what I tried:

```js
const htmlClasses1 = document.getElementsByClassName("samepart-");
console.log(htmlClasses1[0]);

const htmlClasses2 = document.getElementsByClassName('*["samepart-"]');
console.log(htmlClasses2[0]);

const htmlClasses3 = document.getElementsByClassName('[class*="samepart-"]');
console.log(htmlClasses3[0]);

const htmlClasses4 = document.getElementsByClassName(["samepart-"]);
console.log(htmlClasses4[0]);
```

```css
div[class*="samepart-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="samepart-a">some html a</div>
<div class="samepart-b">some html b</div>
<div class="samepart-c">some html c</div>
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName([class^='samepart-']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll()` :

*PS: I edited `*=` to `^=` since it seems you only want classes starting with `samepart`.*

```js
const htmlClasses = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='samepart-']");
console.log(htmlClasses);
```

```css
div[class*="samepart-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #00F;
  color: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="samepart-a">some html a</div>
<div class="samepart-b">some html b</div>
<div class="samepart-c">some html c</div>
```

Comment: can you explain what the difference is between `*=` and `^=`?

Comment: It only selects attributes *starting* with what comes next, instead of `*` which only checks if the attribute contains what comes next.

Comment: So that works the same for the css? That would be nice.

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 2):

try `document.querySelectorAll('[class*="samepart-"]')`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[class*="samepart-"]'))
```

```html
<div class="samepart-a">some html a</div>
<div class="samepart-b">some html b</div>
<div class="samepart-c">some html c</div>
```